# input string was not in a correct format

Tags: asp.net, gridview

[image]In my gridview,I have a footer template whith an insert link button, TextBox and DropDownList.In gridview I have the edit,update and delete options and in footer template,in ddl I have values from another tables,like cities,nationality, high school, etc. When I click the button "Insert" I have this error: input string was not in a correct format . I think I have to convert the values from the ddl, because in my db I use lookup wizard. Here is my cs code:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Admitere1.Controale
{
    public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void lbInsert_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            TextBox txtNume = (TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNume");
            TextBox txtPrenume = (TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPrenume");
            TextBox txtPTata = (TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPTata");
            DropDownList ddlSex = (DropDownList)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlSex");
            DropDownList ddlLN = (DropDownList)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlLN");
            DropDownList ddlLD = (DropDownList)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlLD");
            DropDownList ddlNationalitate = (DropDownList)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlNationalitate");
            TextBox txtCnp = (TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCnp");
            TextBox txtSerie = (TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("txtSerie");
            TextBox txtNumar = (TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNumar");
            TextBox txtTelefon = (TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("txtTelefon");
            TextBox txtEmail = (TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmail");
            DropDownList ddlLiceu = (DropDownList)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlLiceu");
            DropDownList ddlSala = (DropDownList)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlSala");
            DropDownList ddlAdmis = (DropDownList)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlAdmis");
            DropDownList ddlUser = (DropDownList)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlUser");



            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Nume"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNume")).Text;
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Prenume"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPrenume")).Text;
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["prenumeTata"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPTata")).Text;
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Sex"].DefaultValue = ((DropDownList)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlSex")).SelectedValue;
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["LocalitateNastere"].DefaultValue = ((DropDownList)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlLN")).SelectedValue;
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["LocalitateDomiciliu"].DefaultValue = ((DropDownList)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlLD")).SelectedValue;
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Nationalitate"].DefaultValue = ((DropDownList)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlNationalitate")).SelectedValue; ;
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Cnp"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCnp")).Text;
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["SerieCI"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("txtSerie")).Text;
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["NumarCI"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNumar")).Text;
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Telefon"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("txtTelefon")).Text;
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Email"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmail")).Text;
         //   SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["A2aFacultate"].DefaultValue = ((CheckBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ckFac")).Text;
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Liceu"].DefaultValue = ((DropDownList)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlLiceu")).SelectedValue;
           // SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Inmatriculat"].DefaultValue = ((CheckBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ckInmatriculat")).Text;
           // SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Inmatriculat"].DefaultValue = ((CheckBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ckInmatriculat")).Text;
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Sala"].DefaultValue = ((DropDownList)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlSala")).SelectedValue;
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["admisLa"].DefaultValue = ((DropDownList)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlAdmis")).SelectedValue;
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["User"].DefaultValue = ((DropDownList)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlUser")).SelectedValue;

            SqlDataSource1.Insert();
            this.GridView3.ShowFooter = true;
            this.GridView3.DataBind();
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);

        }




         }
}

 And a part of my ascx code:

     <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="idCandidat" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ShowFooter="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="idCandidat" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="idCandidat">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("idCandidat") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("idCandidat") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ValidationGroup="INSERT" OnClick="lbInsert_Click" ID="lbInsert" runat="server">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="nume" SortExpression="nume">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("nume") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="eqNume" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Introduceţi numele"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("nume") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNume" runat="server" style="margin-top: 15px"></asp:TextBox>
                 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="INSERT" ID="eqInsertNume" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Introduceţi numele"
                    ControlToValidate="txtNume" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
.............................................................................

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="user" SortExpression="user">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox16" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("user") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="eqUser" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Introduceţi userul"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox16" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("user") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUser" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource8" DataTextField="email" DataValueField="email" Height="21px"  Width="126px" style="margin-top:15px" >
            <asp:ListItem>User</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource8" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString9 %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString9.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [email] FROM [USERI]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="INSERT" ID="eqInsertUser" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Introduceţi userul"
                    ControlToValidate="ddlUser" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ValidationGroup="INSERT" ID="ValidationSummary1" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" />
    <p>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary2" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" />
        <p>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString9 %>" 
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [CANDIDATI] WHERE [idCandidat] = ?" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [CANDIDATI] ([idCandidat], [nume], [prenume], [prenumeTata], [sex], [localitateNastere], [localitateDomiciliu], [nationalitate], [cnp], [serieCI], [numarCI], [telefon], [email], [a2aFacultate], [liceu], [înmatriculat], [sala], [admisLa], [user]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString9.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [CANDIDATI]" 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [CANDIDATI] SET [nume] = ?, [prenume] = ?, [prenumeTata] = ?, [sex] = ?, [localitateNastere] = ?, [localitateDomiciliu] = ?, [nationalitate] = ?, [cnp] = ?, [serieCI] = ?, [numarCI] = ?, [telefon] = ?, [email] = ?, [a2aFacultate] = ?, [liceu] = ?, [înmatriculat] = ?, [sala] = ?, [admisLa] = ?, [user] = ? WHERE [idCandidat] = ?">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="idCandidat" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="idCandidat" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="nume" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="prenume" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="prenumeTata" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="sex" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="localitateNastere" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="localitateDomiciliu" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="nationalitate" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="cnp" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="serieCI" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="numarCI" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="telefon" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="a2aFacultate" Type="Boolean" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="liceu" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="înmatriculat" Type="Boolean" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="sala" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="admisLa" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="user" Type="Int32" />
            </InsertParameters>

.................................................................
```

And at the source error:  SqlDataSource1.Insert();
Stack Trace:

> [FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
>      System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +10689507
>      System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +145
>      System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider) +46
>      System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, TypeCode typeCode, IFormatProvider provider) +297
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.GetValue(Object value, String defaultValue, TypeCode type, Boolean convertEmptyStringToNull, Boolean ignoreNullableTypeChanges) +126
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.GetValue(Object value, Boolean ignoreNullableTypeChanges) +63
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.get_ParameterValue() +40
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.GetValues(HttpContext context, Control control) +247
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.InitializeParameters(DbCommand command, ParameterCollection parameters, IDictionary exclusionList) +257
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteInsert(IDictionary values) +196
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.Insert() +19
>      Admitere1.Controale.WebUserControl1.lbInsert_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Iulia\Desktop\LICENTA\Admitere1\Admitere1\Controale\WebUserControl1.ascx.cs:63
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e) +116
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +101
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +9643314
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a direct solution without knowing the values of each control inside the GridView. The error is caused by one or more of the insert parameters with `Type="Int32"` not having an integer as the value passed by its corresponding control. An example is `numarCI`. Try debugging `lblInsert_Click` and check the values of each control that should have an integer.

Comment: The first 3 values are for names...then I have a ddl for sex, the next 2 values are for de city(here I have ddl  where I choose values from a table...but I have the table people and the table cities. the gridview is for table people and in that ddl I choose values from cities...and in people,at the 'city' column I have lookup wizard to the cities table...I think here is the problem because I try to assign to a number a string value(in my table at city I have 1,2.. and in the griview I have to choose from constanta, bucharest...).....and the rest are textbox,dropdownlist or checkbox

Comment: Please make sure that the values that should return integers do return integers. Try debugging and check the values of each. Maybe city's parameter type should be String and not Int32?

Comment: parameters were generated automatically...city's parameter is an Int32 because its value is taken from the table cities...and in my gridview I don't enter a number, I enter a string, a name of a city....and that's because it's easy for user to choose from a list of cities instead of search in the db for the number of a column... and I tried to convert the value...but didn't work